# How to open a mailto: link from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a URL shortening Chrome extension called [Shrtr](http://is.gd/ShrtrExtension). Right now, it allows users to copy the shortened URL to clipboard, but in the next version, I've added the ability to email the shortened URL, using a `mailto:` link (i.e. `mailto:?subject=<original page title>&body=<short URL>`).

The problem is, you cannot just assign `document.location.href = 'mailto...';` from an extension. The following 2 methods worked for me, but with both, I end up with an open blank tab in the browser:

**Method 1: `window.open`**

```
var wnd = window.open(emailUrl);
setTimeOut(function() {
    wnd.close();
}, 500);
```

Notice the need to wait before closing the window. This works (i.e. mail client new message dialog appears, pre-populated), but the new tab remains open.

**Method 2: using `chrome.tabs`**

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl }, function(tab) {
    setTimeOut(function() {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    }, 500);
});
```

Again, works - but tab remains open. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using just a background script currently?

Comment: no, this is a popup html. I have "tabs" permissions.

Comment: hmm what email client are you trying to bring up? Because I use Gmail and the way your method 2 works seems to be fine, I can see the new compose in the newly created tab. Unless you are launching something like outlook or some other native mail client, only then you will have that issue.

Comment: The default mail client for the machine

Comment: Yes but if you were to close that window/tab you would break your app for people who use browser based email clients like Gmail for instance. You "could" potentially track the URL of the newly created tab and see if it opens gmail, if not then you can try removing it.

Comment: Not necessarily - for people who use Gmail as their default mail client, the `mailto:` protocol simply opens a new 'compose' tab in their Gmail tab. The new tab created is a side effect and should be closed.

Comment: hmm right well i found this, maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202613/mailto-link-not-working-in-chrome-extension-popup

Comment: Thanks @1337holiday - same question - no good answer (in fact, the guy tried just what I did in solution 1).

Comment: This code would work fine (except from the popup page) but it is setTimeout not setTimeOut. no capital O. Still have the problem though that you don't want to close the page if Chrome is using a mailto: handler for something like Gmail but you do want to close it if it is using a standalone client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I myself had the same issue, and I figured out how to solve the problem so I thought I would share.

The issue stems from the fact that (I believe) you are calling the below code from your extension popup page.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl }, function(tab) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    }, 500);
});
```

The problem with this is that as soon as a new tab is created, the popup page dies and the callback code is never executed.

We can remedy this by moving that code into a function within the background page whose lifetime is not tied to the popup page:

```
function sendEmail() {
    var emailUrl = "mailto:blah@blah.com";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl }, function(tab) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

and calling it via `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().sendEmail()` from your popup page.

Using the above method, the default email client will be opened, and the new tab will be automatically closed after 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, it works somehow. But after closing the chrome will focus to the right most tab (May not be the previous tab)

Comment: @Yiping you could get around this by storing the active tab id and setting it to active again when after your tab is closed.

Answer (score 7):

```
var emailUrl = "mailto:blah@blah.com";

    chrome.tabs.update({
        url: emailUrl
    });
```

Comment: This is the right answer, the email program launched without changing contents of current tab. Deserve more upvotes.

Comment: Thank you.. simplest solution!

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt u need a close statement like this

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>
```

credits go to Daniel [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

or even something like this

```
//keep a handle to the window you open.

var newWin = window.open('my window', 'http://.../');

...
//some point later in the code
newWin.close();
```

credits go to Tracker1 [Javascript Code to close tab that works in IE, Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301780/javascript-code-to-close-tab-that-works-in-ie-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that's not what I'm looking for: all I need is to open the default mail client, with the subject and body populated. Another open tab is a side-effect. I do not want/need to open another HTML page, only to close it later. Also, you'd notice, your solution's URL uses an `http://` protocol. This would not work with `mailto:`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Please check if it fits your solution space.

I have used the following code to open a mailto client in chrome extension.

```
$('.email').click(function(){
    var hrefString = $(this).attr('href');
    var myWindow = window.open(hrefString, "Opening mail client", "width=200, height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>Opening mail client.Please wait!!</p>");
        setTimeout(function(){ myWindow.close() }, 2000);
    });
```

where the element was :

```
 <a style="padding: 0 0 0 5px;" href="mailto:abc@xyz.com" class="email">
```

This worked for me.

Hope it will help others.

Regards,
Karan Ratra

Comment: Have you tried this in an extension? Since it's using window.open, it would have the same result as my original code.

Comment: Hi   Traveling Tech Guy

I have tried it and its working fine in chrome :) .