# Chrome 49 not launching custom url scheme and mailto within chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension within which there is a page which contain a button to launch custom url scheme :

errorpage.html

```
<form>
  <button class="button" formaction="myextension://" id = "start_app">Open My App</button>
</form>
```

Also I have a mailto link on that page :

```
<a href="mailto:help@coders.com" id = "send_log_btn"> Send Mail</a>
```

They both were working fine before i updated chrome to version 49 from version 48.I don't know wether there is some change in permissions or it is a bug in chrome.

For testing purpose i created a seperate html page outside chrome extension and put above links into it and it is working fine.So i think there may be some change in chrome extension api to support  mailto and custom url scheme protocol.

Any solutions.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792565/how-to-open-a-mailto-link-from-a-chrome-extension

Comment: I have tried that but it only works in mac.In windows and linux as soon as the tab is removed the respective dialog also closes without any user interaction.