# How to add variables from JS file in the HTML mailto- body part?

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

This is regarding a Google Chrome Extension which I am trying to build.

I currently have 2 files. One JS file and one HTMl file.

I want to use the JS variable in my HTML file. But I'm using the "mailto" functionality in my HTMl file. So when someone clicks on the image in the HTML file, it will automatically open the email client for the user and auto-populate the "to", "subject" and the "body" fields.

So, I have one variable in my JS file and I want the value of that variable to attached in the body section of the email inbox.

So, my question is how do I do that?

So here's my JS file -

```
var all_details = "Core = " + core + "\n" + "Workspace GUID = " + workspaceId + "\n" + "Model GUID = " + modelId;

console.log(all_details);
```

// So here, I want all the data from the "all_details" variable in my HTML mailto body field.

Here's my HTML code -

```
<a id= "insert" href="mailto:abc@google.com?subject=Issue &body=${all_details}" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="support.png" width="50" height="50" title="Have questions?"></a>
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
```

So, I want that when I click on the above image (which is fetched from the HTML src), it should open an email inbox (it does open now).

I just want the contents/data from the "all-details" variable from my JS to be pasted in the body section of the email inbox.

Comment: Are you using ES6+? Asking because the `${all_details}` should work in a backtick string (`)

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Only if the HTML is also built in the javascript file which I'm not sure that it is - `"One JS file and one HTMl file."`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding into the `href`, you can use javascript to detect a click on the link and access the variable that way and "redirect" the user to mailto: instead of messing with the `href`. You can also get rid of the `target="_blank"`. Also you don't need the anchor link anyway.

```js
var all_details = "testdata";

document.getElementById("insert").addEventListener("click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     location.href = "mailto:abc@google.com?subject=Issue &body=" + all_details;
});
```

```css
 #insert{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<img id= "insert" border="0" src="support.png" width="50" height="50" title="Have questions?">
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
```

Comment: Only downside: the location has to be hardcoded in the javascript. This wouldn't work for multiple links without also hardcoding those.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I somehow cannot make it work in my Chrome extension. It works when I create a new page and copy the same code but does not work in my Chrome Extension. I know that there are some limitations for the Chrome Extensions but any idea about why is this not working for the chrome extension? 

It does not open the email inbox.

Comment: I don't use Chrome Extensions so I can't assist, but here are some options that might make sense to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34363081/3684265

Comment: Okay, so it eventually worked out. 
If I remove the `e.preventDefault();`, it will work as expected. Not sure why but seems as if it is working now.

Answer (score -1):

You could add an event listener to the *insert* link and append the variable to its **href** that way. An example is below;

```js
let insertA = document.getElementById('insert');
let allDetails = 'test-string';

insertA.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.href = this.href + allDetails;
  console.log(this.href);
})
```

```html
<a id= "insert" href="mailto:abc@google.com?subject=Issue&body=" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="support.png" width="50" height="50" title="Have questions?"></a>
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why this has been downvoted. It does exactly what the OP asked.

Comment: Yes, even this one works. Just had to remove the `e.preventDefault();` and it works as expected. Thanks for the help :)